# How to summarize the number of records in all the tables in mysql?

Tags: mysql

I have multiple databases and each database has multiple tables. I want to summarize the number of records stored in all the databases. What is the best way to do that in mysql? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume number of records as number of rows.

**To find total number of rows present in all the databases:**

```
SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES ;
```

**Group by of rows present in each database :**

```
select table_schema,sum(table_rows) from information_schema.tables group by table_schema order by sum(table_rows) desc;
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Beautiful! That is exactly what I need. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You mean something like ?

```
-- Query to list the size of every table in every database, largest first
SELECT 
     table_schema as `Database`, 
     table_name AS `Table`, 
     round(((data_length + index_length) / 1024 / 1024), 2) `Size in MB` 
FROM information_schema.TABLES 
ORDER BY (data_length + index_length) DESC;
```

Comment: Sorry to confuse you. Actually I want to get the total number of the records which are stored in all the tables in mysql server. So I meant total number not the tatal size. Besides, I need to get the total number of records for all the tables in all the databases,  not the total number of records for all the tables in each database indivitually. I wish I made myself clear. Thanks.

Comment: then try

`SELECT SUM(TABLE_ROWS) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'DB_name';

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all database are user defined excluding the predefined databases in MySQL ('mysql','sys',etc are predefined databases in MySQL).

```
   select sum(t.table_rows) from information_schema.SCHEMATA s inner join 
   information_schema.TABLES t on t.table_schema=s.schema_name where 
   s.schema_name not in 
   ('information_schema','mysql','sys','performance_schema')
```

This query will return the total count of rows in all the tables created by the a user(tables rows in all the databases created by user).